# Running Android MonkeyRunner for mulitple activities

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

I am trying to do some automated testing against a complex Android app and I'm wondering if MonkeyRunner is the right tool. I keep seeing that you need to load the activity you want to test, but what if you want to test multiple activities? Say you start with main, and then want to test a search function? Can MonkeyRunner test across multiple activities in a single test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonkeyRunner starts from a specific `Activity` and continues (by simulating presses) to other activities, if it is possible to move to them by your UI. It doesn't stay on one `Activity`.

Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) to see how to move with it.

Comment: I was looking through the documentation, but didn't see anything about that. I understand about pressing different buttons, but I wasn't sure if you have to implement other activities when they are called or if different activities need different buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work.

```
import os
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

devices = os.popen('adb devices').read().strip().split('\n')[1:];
deviceid1 = devices[0].split('\t')[0];
deviceid2 = devices[1].split('\t')[0];
dev1 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('',deviceid1)
dev2 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('',deviceid2)
```

Now you can start Activity on 2 devices by taking `dev1` or `dev2`.